# Save locally recovered image with Universal image loader

Tags: android, image, universal-image-loader

I'm using Universal Image loader to retrieve a lot of images from a server and showing it inside a listview. 
Now when cache is full, library remove automatically some "old" images for free space to keep new on, so when i scroll "back" for see previous images (that was deleted from cache), library download it again.
This is a very big problem if library recover picture using a 3g connection.

What i want to do is:
-recover picture from link
-save pic in cache (library already do this)
-save pic into a folder on storage too

so when library need to show again an old picutre that is not still into chache, it could recover it from storage, and not from web.

It's possible to do it?

Comment: Did you enable caching on disk?

Answer (score 2):

I think the batter way is you use **UrlImageViewHelper** you can download from  https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper

it will handle automatically store the image in cash memory it's a better way to use this lib to load image.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes you Can First you have to store images in specific folder while doing activity for first time later you can put small piece of code to check that requested file is present on local storage folder ..... thats will solve your Problem